# GC_FOR_MALLOC freed N objects

Tags: android, logcat, dalvik, android-logcat

My Logcat is full of many the following messages interleaved with the messages I am interested in:

```
11-06 18:05:42.129: DEBUG/dalvikvm(853): 
GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 543 objects / 25440 bytes in 46ms
```

I know how to filter **in** messages by TAG and/or by PID, but I don't know how to filter **out**.

My questions:

1. Is there a way to filter **out** those GC_FOR_MALLOC messages?
2. How can those GC_FOR_MALLOC messages be useful for an application
   program (i.e. not system) debug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse 3.6.2 and up with the latest ADT 16, then you can use the following [Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408) in the `by Log Tag` field in the filter:

```
^((?!dalvikvm).)*$
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh wow! I've been waiting for a feature like this. Amazing. Thanks +1.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to filter out those GC_FOR_MALLOC messages?

Like this:

[image]

> How can those GC_FOR_MALLOC messages be useful for an application program (i.e. not system) debug?

GC_FOR_MALLOC means that the Garbage Collection started due to lack of memory on the heap to perform an allocation.

And the log says it freed 543 objects or 25440 bytes in 46ms (which is quite long btw). The DVM was paused for 46ms.

Comment: Thanks +1. This answers my 2nd question.